# Pass multi parameter to CommandParameter in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to pass serval parameters to a command via commandparameter in xaml.

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding HideLineCommand, ElementName=militaryLineAction}"
                       CommandParameter="{Binding ID, ElementName=linesSelector}"/>
```

In above sample, I want to pass others variables to the command beside the ID variable. How can I achieve it? Great thanks.

Comment: It might help to see more of your code. Are `militaryLineAction` and `linesSelector` UI elements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use **MultiBinding** with a **converter**.

Check this example.

Let's suppose that you have Person class.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

And you want this class as your command parameter.

Your XAML should look like this:

```
<Button Content="Start"
                DataContext="{Binding SourceData}"
                >
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SendStatus, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myPersonConverter}">
                                <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                                    <Binding Path="Name" />
                                    <Binding Path="Age" />
                                </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                    </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>
```

Where `SourceData` is a Person object.

And `myPersonConverter` is a PersonConverter object.

```
public class PersonConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {   
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values != null && values.Length == 2)
            {
                string name = values[0].ToString();
                int age = (int)values[1];

                return new Person { Name = name, Age = age }; 
            }
            return null;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

And in your command you can use Person object as parameter:

```
    public ICommand SendStatus { get; private set; }
    private void OnSendStatus(object param)
    {
        Person p = param as Person;
        if (p != null)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is a very useful skill. It works well with this multi-binding implementation. Thanks.

Comment: This really helped me. Thanks @kmatyaszek +1

Comment: This was really helpful, but, might I add, you have to add this converter in app.xaml as in `<Converter:PersonConverter x:Key="myPersonConverter" />`

Comment: Can you update this for 2020/2021 please. Getting errors with imports. Also EventName does not exist anymore.